# System extremely unstable after replacing motherboard

Tags: laptop

I recently replaced the motherboard in my aunts laptop because one of the IT guys she knows from work determined it was defective. Even though I had my doubts about that diagnosis, I ordered a replacement board identical to the defective one.

At this point, the laptop is extremely slow from POST to BIOS it takes 5-10 minutes. When I just let the computer go on its own booting up, it never gets past the HP screen. it only loads that and then automatically reboots itself. That is the only thing it does by itself.

In rare cases, the system is able to start normally, but usually it will just continuously reboot, suggest startup repair or crash completely.

I've tried using a Windows Vista Recovery disc and performing system repair and memory diagnosis. For now, I didn't try the system restore.

Comment: What is the model of your HP laptop?

Comment: hp pavilion DV9428

Answer (score 1):

Bios should never take that long. I suspect a corrupt Mobo driver which you may find through HP-or possible power supply problem (loose connection from re-build or crossed wire...)

Answer (score 0):

Check the processor cooling, i.e. heatsink, thermal compound, fans, etc if it runs hot it may be throttling back. If there is a case/gpu fan, check that too.

Comment: @Tog i had to pull the heatsink to put on the new motherboard but that is the only fan in the laptop. as for the thermal compound i used coolermaster brand,i wanted to add that the only time it shuts itself down is when i let it try to boot itself, and it also crashed when i use the windows diagnostic tool, so does that mean that the heatsink is either installed wrong, or...

Comment: If the heatsink is secure and you didn't overdo the thermal paste then I doubt it's a problem. Have you reseated the memory since fitting it? Also, did you take any precautions against static discharge?

Comment: the thermal compound i just put one small bead down the center of teh chip, so when i sat it down it spread evenly..  and i dont know what you mean as far as re-seating the memory since fitting it. also i did wear a anti-static wristband while handling all the components. BUT one thing i did do but didnt think may have been bad was. i worked ontop of a table with a white towle spread out so i could see well.. could static have came from that directly?

Comment: When you replaced the motherboard you must have swapped over the memory from the old one, have you tried removing then refitting (reseating) the memory? If that makes no difference and you have more than one stick of memory, try using just one stick at a time. Towels can produce static but I think you would have noticed the towel clinging to itself if that was the case.

Comment: well yeah i did carry over the old memory from the other board. ill get on reseating it and get back to you. one thing on that though does it matter about the slot itself? meaning when/if i need to try one at a time should i try each one in each different slot?

Comment: ok man i did the reseating and then tried running just 1 at a time.. still had the same problem with the computer automaticly rebooting before it has a chance to bootup..

Comment: For reference the maintenance manual is here http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01311536.pdf and the upgrade guide is here http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00820047&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&site=null&lang=en&product=3446408&key=null#InstallMemory but I can't find any reference to the memory slots. I would go for the one closest to the MB first, you won't damage the memory

Comment: At this point I would be tempted to refit the original board and see if you can get it back to the original fault. At least that way you can be reasonably sure you haven't damaged anything.

Comment: If you do refit the original MB, go into the BIOS and record your settings, there may be some none-default settings required for your laptop hardware. Just a thought.